# Undocumented TypeError: Failed to fetch in valid json response in swagger

Tags: json, swagger, response, postman

I would like to make swagger client document for my backend.
And I have problem with getting json response.(I tested signup api)
When I try signup using swagger client, I can confirm that new user saved correctly in database. but it can't get json response what my api send.
This is swagger part.

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: successful operation
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/ApiResponse'
 definitions:
  ApiResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      result:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      errorCode:
        type: string
      errorMsg:
        type: string
```

When I test api using postman, it send this json object with status code 200

```
{
   "result":false,
   "errorCode":"00002",
   "errorMsg": "Same Account already exists!"
}
```

but in swagger, it says

```
Code                 Details
Undocumented         TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

It saves data correctly, only I can't get json response.
Thanks.

Comment: Might be CORS issue. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support

Comment: Something I have noticed is that the "result" type should be a boolean.